# Is there any function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\cup \{\pm \infty\}$ such that $f$ is lower semi continuous only at $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: real-analysis, semicontinuous-functions

Is there any function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\cup \{\pm \infty\}$ such that $f$ is lower semi continuous only at $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

A function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\cup \{\pm \infty\}$ is said to be lower semi continuous on $A$ if the set $\{x\in A : f(x) \le \alpha\}$ is closed for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}  $  .

Other equivalent definition, $f$ is lower semi continuous at $x_o$ if $$\lim_{\delta \to 0}m_{\delta} (x_o) =f(x_o) $$

\begin{align} m_{\delta} (x_o) &=inf \{f(x) : x\in (x_o - \delta,x_o+ \delta)\}\\ \end{align}

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I think $1-\chi_\mathbb{Q}$(The characterisitc function of irrationals) would do its job.

Answer (score 3):

If all you want to know is "Is there ..."  as opposed to "Construct one for me ..."  then there is this study by Z. Grande:

> Grande, Zbigniew.  *Quelques remarques sur la semi-continuité
> supérieure*. [Some remarks on upper semicontinuity] Fund.
> Math. 126 (1985), no. 1, 1–13.

http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm126/fm12611.pdf

He shows that **any** set of reals can be the set of points of upper semi-continuity for a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.

In fact he shows that if $A$ and $B$ are real sets,  $B\subset A$, $B$ is a set of type ${\cal G}_\delta$, and $B$ is dense in the interior of $A$ then there is a function   $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ whose set of points of continuity is precisely $B$ and whose set of points of upper semicontinuity is precisely $A$.

So there is nothing very special about the rationals that makes the problem interesting or worth losing sleep over.